# How to get data from a combo-box vb

Tags: vb.net, list, combobox

I am trying to get all the data from a combo-box in vb. Lets say the values are john, sarah, bob. I want to be able to write those to a text file like this:

John
Sarah
Bob

They were added using

```
combobox.add.item(sarah)
```

Is there anyway I can do somthing like this?

```
names = combobox.list.items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In c# it would be something like this

```
string names = string.Join(", ", comboBox.Items.Cast<object>()
                                         .Select(i => i.ToString()));
```

Here's the same snippet (auto)translated to vb.net

```
Dim names As String = String.Join(", ", comboBox.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(i) i.ToString()))
```

Or you can do a simple loop through all the items and use a stringbuilder and concatenate each item.

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
For Each item As Object In comboBox.Items
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", item)
Next
Dim names As String = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: is this for VB.net, because it doesn't recognise stringbuilder or var?

Comment: @Kuzon include `Imports System.Text` for `StringBuilder`.

Comment: It is still giving me system.windows.forms.combobox+objectcollection

    Private Sub btnbwsworld_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnworld.Click

        cmbworld.Items.Add("test")

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

        For Each item As var In cmbworld.Items

            sb.AppendFormat("{0}, ", item)

        Next

        Dim names As String = sb.ToString()

        MsgBox(names)

    End Sub

Comment: @Kuzon instead of var, try Object (I have changed that in my answer)

Comment: @Bala R I don't think that it is a error message, I think it might be the value of names. The msgbox(names) will come up with the text "system.windows.forms.combobox+objectcollection"

Comment: @Kuzon I have no idea then. I have the same code but in c# and it works and the translation to vb.net is pretty straightforward so I'm not sure. Maybe someone else will come along and point out what's going on.