# How do i concatenate uin of list of item i vb.net

Tags: vb.net, join, concatenation

I do have a multi select dropdown box.

I want all the selected items uin in a string with comma seperated value.

Currently I am doing as following:

```
        Dim SelUINS As String = ""

        For Each Item As SalesCustomer In RetailerMainListBox.SelectedItems
            SelUINS += Item.Uin & ","
        Next
        SelUINS = Strings.Left(SelUINS, SelUINS.Length - 1)
```

I want a shortcut like join to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help :

```
Dim names As String = String.Join(", ", RetailerMainListBox.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Select(Function(i) i.Uin.ToString()))
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325567/how-to-get-data-from-a-combo-box-vb)

Comment: was helpful.... though for exact result i need to change i.tostring to i.uin.tostring... :) thnx